# Differential Equations (ODE)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Using the substitution $u(x)=y+x$ to solve the differential equation

$$\frac{dy}{dx}= (y+x)^2$$

When attempting this, I got

$$y=\frac{1}{3}u(x)^3+C$$ which is;

$y=\frac{1}{3}(y+x)^3+C$. I'm not sure if that is right but if it is, how would I solve for $y$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = (y+x)^2 \implies 1+\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx} (y+x) = 1+(y+x)^2$$

Let $u=y+x$ so that the equation becomes

$$\frac{du}{dx} = 1+u^2$$

or

$$\frac{du}{1+u^2} = dx \implies \arctan{u} = x + C$$

where $C$ is a constant of integration.  Thus

$$u = y+x = \tan{(x+C)} \implies y = \tan{(x+C)}-x$$

Comment: how did you get 1+dy/dx=d/dx(y+x)

Comment: $$\frac{dx}{dx} = 1$$

Comment: I am still a bit lost. Why do you have dx/dx?

Comment: It's a trick that allows me to make the ODE separable.  This sort of trick is hard to teach - you just have to be able to pattern match.